# Deedle (F#) : System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier error

Tags: dataframe, f#, deedle

(edit) i'm using F# interactive in Xamarin 6.3 on MacOS Sierra and Deedle 1.2.5 together with FsLab –

I'm trying this code taken from http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/frame.html

and this produces an error.

```
type Person = 
  { Name:string; Age:int; Countries:string list; }

let peopleRecds = 
  [ { Name = "Joe"; Age = 51; Countries = [ "UK"; "US"; "UK"] }
    { Name = "Tomas"; Age = 28; Countries = [ "CZ"; "UK"; "US"; "CZ" ] }
    { Name = "Eve"; Age = 2; Countries = [ "FR" ] }
    { Name = "Suzanne"; Age = 15; Countries = [ "US" ] } ]

// Turn the list of records into data frame 
let peopleList = Frame.ofRecords peopleRecds
// Use the 'Name' column as a key (of type string)
let people = peopleList |> Frame.indexRowsString "Name"

people?Age;;
 val it : Series<string,float> =
 Joe     -> 51 
 Tomas   -> 28 
 Eve     -> 2  
 Suzanne -> 15 

people.Columns?Age.TryAs<string>();;
```

> Stopped due to error  System.Exception: Operation could not be
>   completed due to earlier error  Lookup on object of indeterminate type
>   based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation
>   may be

Comment: What are you using to run the code? How are you running it? This seems to work fine for me, but I'm using VS 2015 and script files...

Comment: i'm using in F# interactive in Xamarin 6.3 on MacOS Sierra
Deedle 1.2.5 together with FsLab

Comment: That's strange - are you running the script from F# Interactive or from command line? On which line is the error reported?

Comment: i am running from F# interactive